# Navbar only start and end links working HTML

Tags: html, css

So I have a header with a navbar and some links like this.
[image: My Navbar]

When I hover on a link I have a border around it that looks like this.
[image]

Now only the **HOME** and **CONTACT** links are working and showing the cursors as a pointer and displaying the borders on hover but the other four aren't working or even showing a cursor to indicate that it's a link. How to fix this? Thanks.

Here's my header code:

```
<header>
    <div class="navbar" id="navbar">
        <div class="link" id="link">
            <a href="">HOME</a> 
        </div>
        <div class="link" id="link">
            <a href="#about">ABOUT</a> 
        </div>
        <div class="link" id="link">
            <a href="">OUR SERVICES</a> 
        </div>
        <div class="link" id="link">
            <a href="#gallery">PORTFOLIO</a> 
        </div>
        <div class="link" id="link">
            <a href="">CLIENT ALBUMS</a> 
        </div>
        <div class="link" id="link">
            <a href="#contact">CONTACT</a> 
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="burger-menu">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="burger-style" id="showNavs">
            <i class="fa fa-bars" style="color: black;"></i>
          </a>
    </div>
   
</header>
```

And here's my CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
header > .navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 1em;
    padding-top: 1.2em;
    margin-left: 3em;
    margin-right: 3em;
}


#link {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: calc(5px + 1vw);
    padding: .5em;
    border: 2px solid white;
}

#link:hover {
    transition: .5s;
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding-top: .5em;
    padding-bottom: .5em;
    padding-left: 2.5em;
    padding-right: 2.5em;
}
```

}

It doesn't work even though I already changed from classes to ids.

Here's my Jquery code but I don't think this is really relevant for this problem.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var navbar = $("#navbar")
        var showNavs = $("#showNavs")

        $("#showNavs").click(function() {
            navbar.toggle("slow")
            
        })

    

        var form = $("#contact-form")
        var firstName = form.find("#firstName")
        var lastName = form.find("#lastName")
        var textarea = form.find("#textarea")
        form.submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            firstName.val('')
            lastName.val('')
            textarea.val('')
        })

        var newsletterForm = $("#newsletter-form")
        newsletterForm.submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $(this).find("#email").val('')
        })


       
    })
```

Here's a full demo of my site.
[Wedding Planner Website](https://therealgodwin.github.io/wedding-planner-website/)

The links are working fine when the browser isn't resized.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question with [minimal reproducible demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can actually see what is wrong

Comment: I just added the link to my website so that you can check it out.

Comment: I have opened this site on chrome, firefox, opera and safari and it works for me. Every element is behaving like link.

Comment: did you try to resize the browser? Because on my local and production server when I resize the window all the links are not working.

Comment: I have resized to min 600px (because then it changes into hamburger menu) and yes, it worked.

Comment: Maybe you meant that not whole border element is a link but rather only text?

Comment: I meant that the links aren't working when the browser is resized. only the starting link and the ending links are working, in this case HOME and CONTACT.

Comment: maybe (just maybe) it is the problem with your `id` attributes? From [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) `The id global attribute defines an identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document.` and yet you have 6 elements with `id="link"`

Answer (score 0):

To Change the cursor to a pointer when you hover over something element add The Following In Your Styles:

```css
cursor: pointer;
```

this will work regardless of the element when a user hovers over the element.
If It Works Please Mark As Correct!
Kamestart

(If It Does Not Work Please Share Your Code And Write In The Comments. It Will Help A lot.)

Edit: It Wont Work. If You Want To Stay On The Same Fir Testing Purposes Use # in the href attr. if it is empty it will not be recognised as a link.

Comment: No, I was just illustrating that the links don't get recognized as links and they don't work. Only the HOME and CONTACT links work, even when the browser gets resized.

Comment: Can You Please Edit The Question And Share Your Code.

Comment: Please Check Now :).

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I edited the answer. please refer to edit in the answer.

Comment: It still didn't do anything.

Comment: What Do You Mean. It Works Perfectly when I reproduce the issue.

Comment: @kamestart what is your environment? I cannot reproduce this issue.

Comment: i am using visula studio code and live server.

Comment: @kamestart windows?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you wrap your div's with anchor tag so the whole box will be clickable and also I looked at your site, there's a `class="text-container"` which is overlapping your Navbar when the window is resized, hope you'll know the reason now.
[image]

```css
.navbar{
display:flex;
justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="navbar"  id="navbar">
    <a href="">
      <div class="link" id="link">
        HOME
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#about">
      <div class="link" id="link">
        ABOUT
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <div class="link" id="link">
        OUR SERVICES
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#gallery">
      <div class="link" id="link">
        PORTFOLIO
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <div class="link" id="link">
        CLIENT ALBUMS
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#contact">
      <div class="link" id="link">
        CONTACT
      </div>
    </a>

  </div>

  <div class="burger-menu">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="burger-style" id="showNavs">
      <i class="fa fa-bars" style="color: black;"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
```